# Styling the navigation bar in UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

In my app, the primary theme has blue navigation bars with white bar button items and titles.

[image]

I set the values for colors like this in the App Delegate.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = AppColors.blue
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

But in some view controllers, I'm required to invert these styles (white navigation bars with blue buttons and titles).

[image]

So in those view controllers, I simply set the new values in the `viewWillAppear` method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = AppColors.blue
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: AppColors.blue]
}
```

From one of these view controllers, I have to show a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to pick a document file.

```
let documentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
documentPickerViewController.delegate = self
present(documentPickerViewController, animated: true)
```

The user can preview it as well. I use the QuickLook framework to do that.

The problem is these view controllers, `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and `QLPreviewController` don't conform to the new navigation bar color values I set in the `viewWillAppear` method.

[image]

Master view controller has the blue navigation bar but the detail view's navigation bar is all white. Including the bar button items. So the buttons are not visible. It seems the values I set in the `viewWillAppear` method has no effect here. I commented out the `appearance` values from the App Delegate and the buttons show up in the default colors.

[image]

Same with the `QLPreviewController` view controller.

[image]

[image]

I tried having the presenting view controller conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate` but that didn't work.

I also tried getting a reference to the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`'s navigation controller like this `documentPickerViewController.navigationController` but it returns `nil` as well.

How do I apply colors to the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` without changing the `appearance` values?

I uploaded a demo project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ht21naabwwrcai/DocumentPicker.zip?dl=0).

Comment: So, you've tried to set the detail view controller's nav controller?

Comment: I have no control over it. It's just how iOS show the document picker on iPads. In a master detail view.

Comment: even `documentPickerViewController.splitViewController?.detailViewController`?

Comment: That returns nil too.

Comment: I see, just check the view hierarchy, yes, the split view is inside some container view controller...

Comment: I just did. There's only one child view controller and it's a UIDocumentBrowserViewController.

Comment: I think you can temporally use `documentPickerViewController .browserUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` before find a better solution

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to reference the browser from the document picker controller.